# Resize code does not correspond with mouse movement

Tags: java, swing, resize, awt, mouse

I have some code to resize a chatpanel dynamically, but it does not move according to the mouse. What happens is the mouse moves at a faster rate than the panel gets resized. For example, how I want it to be, is in any application, when you click on the border between two windows, and drag it, the mouse stays along with the piece you are clicking on, and currently this is not happening. here is my code. please let me know if you need more

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if(getCursor().getType() == Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR).getType()) {
        owner.adjust((int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY());
        System.out.println("vertpanel: "+(int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY());
    }
}
public void adjust(int adjustment) {
int height = this.getHeight();
    System.out.println((((double)(adjustment))/height)+":"+(((double)(height-adjustment))/height));
output.setHeightPercent((((double)(adjustment))/height));
output.componentResized(new ComponentEvent(this, 1));
input.setHeightPercent((((double)(height-adjustment))/height));
input.componentResized(new ComponentEvent(this, 2));
}
```

there is one main panel, a chatpanel, and within it, there are two smaller panels, a chat input and a chat output

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Can't tell exactly what you are doing based on your code.

I would suggest that you should NOT be manually setting the dimensions of the output and input coponents. You should let the layout manager determine how to resize each component as the parent container is resized.

So in your resize code you would need to invoke revalidate() on the parent container as it is resized.

Check out [Resizing Components](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/). You should be able to use the `ComponentResizer` class as long as you use `setAutoLayout(true)`.

Comment: The idea behind what Im doing is this. There is a separator panel between the chat input and chat output. That panel listens for mouse events, and on drag events, sets the percentage of the parents height each panel should be. Then the resize method on those panels is called so that they properly resize. For some reason though, the mouse moves faster than the components resize, so its not in sync with the drag

Comment: Just use a JSplitPane. It will handle the resizing of the components automatically.