# How to make Resizable panel in frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am new to swing and i want to create the Resizable panel under frame.
I want to create the UI using swing as below.
How can i make it. please help me

[image]

Comment: What do you have now? Can you post your code? Please post a Minimal Working Example!

Comment: You can achive that with help of [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: A LayoutManager is what you will probably *not* need here when you want to resize the "panel" manually, with the mouse, by dragging the handles at the corners. But it is still not clear enough what your requirements and previous approaches are to give a more constructive answer...

Comment: Maybe you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17012161/261156).